# Using wildcard routes and url_helpers in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, wildcard, form-helpers

I have a wildcard route set up - but I cannot get the built in helpers to generate the correct url.

`routes.rb`

```
resources :projects do
    patch 'do/*action', to: 'projects#do', as: 'do'
end
```

`rake routes`

```
project_do PATCH  /projects/:project_id/do/*action(.:format)         projects#do
```

which looks ok, but my helper `project_do_path(project)` generates `/projects/1234/do/do`

1) why how do I get rid of the second `do`
2) can I configure it to include the action in the helper?

I have read `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments` but it does not talk about helpers in the wildcard section.

thanks and best regards

Comment: change `action` to a different name since that equates to `params[:action]`.  try `patch 'do/*do_action'`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - helper still generates `.../do/do`

Comment: that should work but you need to pass a second argument.  `project_do_path(project, 'asd')` then `params[:do_action]` will be set to `asd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the following routes

```
resources :blog, only: [:index, :show] do
  patch 'do/*do_action', to: 'rsvps#index', as: :do
end
```

gives me the following url

```
   blog_do PATCH  /blog/:blog_id/do/*do_action(.:format)    rsvps#index
blog_index GET    /blog(.:format)                           blog#index
      blog GET    /blog/:id(.:format)                       blog#show
```

`blog_do_path` now requires 2 arguments

```
blog_do_path(project, 'asd')
```

then in your controller action, `params[:do_action]` will be `'asd'`